# Deleted /Users/user/.gradle/caches and flutter stop working

Tags: flutter, gradle

I was trying to solve a problem with `flutter build appbundle` when I saw a solution on a forum that suggested to deleted the `/Users/user/.gradle/caches` folder, and now I'm getting this error when I try to run my app:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2f2881f4cceb526aca8e817e92e637d5/transformed/jetified-firebase-functions-20.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I already tried to `clean`, `pub get` and `run` the flutter app again, but it is still doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the whole `/Users/user/.gradle/` folder and now it is working.